# wordpress shortcode strange behaviour on password protected page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, output-buffering

I've written a wordpress plugin for a friends homepage. It should output a form on a password protected page. I've written this plugin on march 2013. The form is included into the page via shortcode. At that time I printed my output directly via echo. Now my friend told me that the plugin isn't working anymore. I looked at the API docs and found out that I should return the shortcode output so I included my output in an output buffer and returned that content.

The shortcode is embedded in a password protected page. If I am not logged in into wordpress and haven't entered the password, the shortcode content is displayed at the top of the page. If I enter the password, nothing is printed. If I am logged in into wordpress, everythin is fine. Before I enter the password I see nothing, after entering the password I see everything at the right place.

Any ideas?

Best regards,
Sebastian

Comment: Just a wild guess... but could it have something to do with where/how you are processing the form? The $_POST might be getting processed even for the password entry stage and thus causing your own form to misbehave.

Comment: I can't imagine how this could be the problem. The output of my shortcode is more or less independent from the $_POST values. And it shouldn't work for logged in users, too, if that's the reason.

Comment: Have you managed to sort it out? The content appearing at the top of the page seems to suggest that the output is not captured. Is it possible to post some of the code so we can try to pinpoint the problem?